# Using a Form Widget Validator on multiple fields

Tags: plone, z3c.form

I've written a custom validator for my schema field as shown in the documentation here:
http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/forms/z3c.form.html#form-widget-validators

[image]

My question is that if i want to use the same validator for a few different fields, is that possible? It doesnt seem to work. eg I would like to write:

```
# Set conditions for which fields the validator class applies
validator.WidgetValidatorDiscriminators(PhoneNumberValidator, field=IZohoContactForm['phone_number'])
validator.WidgetValidatorDiscriminators(PhoneNumberValidator, field=IZohoContactForm['another_phone_field'])
```

Comment: Using the same validator on multiple fields should work without any problems. Do you get an error trace?

Comment: The behaviour i am seeing is that the second registration overwrites the first... ie if i have field A, B and register the validator for A and then B (as in my example) it only fires for field B.
If i swap order of the registration so register B then A, it only fires for field A.
It's like last in wins... and no, no errors.

Comment: Do you need to call that with a list of fields the validator applies to? https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.form/blob/54d7afe0320cb43b41c17596d844fa9cb21535e4/src/z3c/form/validator.txt#L166 says "to set the discriminators" (plural).

Comment: I would expect you could pass it a list ideally or multiple parameters but in  z3c.form.validator.py :125 it looks like it only accepts a single field?
def WidgetValidatorDiscriminators(
    validator, context=None, request=None, view=None, field=None, widget=None):
    zope.component.adapter(
        util.getSpecification(context),
        util.getSpecification(request),
        util.getSpecification(view),
        util.getSpecification(field),
        util.getSpecification(widget))(validator)

Comment: As a workaround I have written two identical validators with different names which violates the DRY principle but not much i can for this one it seems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I have written two identical validators with different names which violates the DRY principle but not much i can for this one it seems...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass a field **type** as well for the `field` argument
(see: https://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/schema-driven-forms/customising-form-behaviour/validation.html#field-widget-validators): `validator.WidgetValidatorDiscriminators(MyListValidator, field=schema.List)`

In the above example the validator is applied to all fields of type `schema.List`

Comment: This question is 5 years old and you are likely will not get a response.  This may be better suited for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I just recently faced this problem and this is my approach:

1. Set a schema interface for the field to be validated.

```
class ICaptchaSchema(model.Schema):
    captcha = schema.TextLine(
            title=_('security_check', default="Security check"),
        )
```

2. Use the field in form schema interface:

```
class IFormSchema(model.Schema):
    captcha1 = ICaptchaSchema['captcha']
    captcha2 = ICaptchaSchema['captcha']
```

3. Register form widget validator for the first schema iterface:

```
validator.WidgetValidatorDiscriminators(YourCustomValidator,
                                        field=ICaptchaSchema['captcha'])
```

All fields "captcha" will be adapted.

Regards.